# Como desmarcar um checkbox quando outro é selecionado?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, jsf, jsp

```
<t:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection"
                        forceId="true" forceIdIndex="false" id="selectCodigoProcesso"
                        rendered="#{!bkbCadastroPessoaJuridica.orgaoEntidade}"
                        styleClass="envolveRadio"
                        valueChangeListener="#{actCadastroPessoaJuridica.selecaoCnpjNomeLst}"
                        onclick="setColorRadioGroupJSF();mudaInput('selectCodigoProcesso'); SetSel(selectCodigoProcesso);"
                        binding="#{actCadastroPessoaJuridica.selectRadioCnpj}">
                        <!-- Olá mundo -->
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="cnpj" id="codigoProcesso" itemLabel="" />

                    </t:selectOneRadio>


<t:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection"
                        forceId="true" forceIdIndex="false" id="selectCodigoProcesso"
                        rendered="#{!bkbCadastroPessoaJuridica.orgaoEntidade}"
                        styleClass="envolveRadio"
                        valueChangeListener="#{actCadastroPessoaJuridica.selecaoCnpjNomeLst}"
                        onclick="setColorRadioGroupJSF();mudaInput('selectCodigoProcesso'); SetSel(selectCodigoProcesso);"
                        binding="#{actCadastroPessoaJuridica.selectRadioCnpj}">
                        <!-- Olá mundo -->
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="cnpj" id="codigoProcesso" itemLabel="" />

                    </t:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento? coloca o código do mudaInput();

Comment: function mudaInput (nameRadio) {
     //alert("body on load mudaInput document.getElementById(nameRadio)"+document.getElementById(nameRadio));
        if(document.getElementById(nameRadio) != null){
        //  alert("entrou mudaInput");
         var objects = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
         for (var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
            thisElement = objects[i];

Comment: if (thisElement.getAttribute("type") == "radio") {
              //  window.alert (thisElement.name);
                //window.alert (nameRadio);
                 //alert("thisElement.name"+thisElement.name);
           // alert("nameRadio"+nameRadio);
                
                if (thisElement.checked && thisElement.name == nameRadio) {
                    radioSelecionado = thisElement.value;                    
                }
            }
         }

Comment: var objects = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
 for (var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
  var thisElement = objects[i];
  if (thisElement.getAttribute("type") == "text")
                {
                    if (radioSelecionado == "cnpj") {
                        if (thisElement.id == "form:numero") {
                            thisElement.disabled = false;                            
                        }               
                        else {
                            //thisElement.disabled = true;
                        }

Comment: } else if (radioSelecionado == "nome") {
                        if (thisElement.id == "form:textoPesquisa") {
                            thisElement.disabled = false;
                        } else {
                            //thisElement.disabled = true;
                        }                        
                    }
                }
 } 
  } else  {

Comment: var objects = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
         for (var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
            thisElement = objects[i];
           
            if (thisElement.getAttribute("type") == "radio") {
              thisElement.checked = false;
              
         }
     
  }
}
}

Comment: coloca na pergunta e nao nos comentários.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil você alterar seu HTML e em vez de usar a Checkbox usar botões Radio?? Botões Radio já tem essa função (desmarcar um ao marcar o outro) de forma nativa.